# Any alternative for absolute file paths for sub-processes when we convert .py into .exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, pyinstaller

I used `pyinstaller` to convert two files from `.py` to `.exe` . My `file(A).exe` has `subprocess.Popen` and it runs `file(B).exe` . `File(A)` runs just fine.

Now I have used absolute path for `file(B)` in `file(A)`.

***My question*** : Is there anyway to avoid using absolute path?

*For example*, just use shortcuts of both files in the same directory.

In this way I can run my code on any machine.

Comment: Use relative paths, or no paths and have both executables in the same folder.

Comment: now I am not sure about putting both executables in same folder. There are many associated files which are generated in build folder along with .exe. These files support .exe in running. Overlapping may hamper the process.

Comment: Well sibling folders sounds about right: Put `A.exe` in `folderA` and `B.exe` in `folderB`, so A will call B using this filename: `../folderB/B.exe`.

Comment: you could consider a `config` file for `A.exe` which contains the location of `B.exe`. Or you can consider a `sys.argv()` or similar to parse the command line arguments for `A.exe`, which then points to the location of `B.exe`. Finally when on windows only, you can use the windows registry to store the location of `B.exe` and retrieve it in `A.exe`

Comment: @quamrana I think this should settle relative path option. Thank you!

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo Frankly I am too new to programming itself. It would be nice if you can give some detail or provide some detailed source. I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: @TheOne I would suggest you search (using your favorite search engine) for sample code for `sys.argv()` or `configparser`. Experiment a bit, and if you find yourself stuck, you can always come back here with a well structured question. Unfortunately SO is not a place for tutorials. Good Luck.

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo understood. Thank You!